# Create an object with empty constructor

Tags: c++

I have the following code and it doesn't compile when I create an object with an empty constructor like so:

```
PriorityQueue pq1();
pq1.insert(3); // doesn't compile
```

But it does compile like this:

```
PriorityQueue pq2 = PriorityQueue();
pq2.insert(3); // compiles
```

Why does that happen ?

**PriorityQueue.h**

```
class PriorityQueue
{
public:
    PriorityQueue();  // Create the heap
    ~PriorityQueue(); // Destroy the heap
}
```

**PriorityQueue.cpp**

```
#include "PriorityQueue.h"

PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue()
{

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "PriorityQueue.h"

int main()
{
    PriorityQueue pq1();
    pq1.insert(3); // doesn't compile

    PriorityQueue pq2 = PriorityQueue();
    pq2.insert(3); // compiles
}
```

Comment: `PriorityQueue pq1();` should be `PriorityQueue pq1;` otherwise it is a function declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PriorityQueue pq1();
```

The above statement doesn't create an object. It is a function declaration of `pq1` whose return type is `PriorityQueue`.

```
PriorityQueue pq1; // Remove ()
```

[Most Vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)